# Testing if an Object is a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, dictionary

Is there a way to test if an object is a dictionary?

In a method I'm trying to get a value from a selected item in a list box.  In some circumstances, the list box might be bound to a dictionary, but this isn't known at compile time.

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
if (listBox.ItemsSource is Dictionary<??>)
{
    KeyValuePair<??> pair = (KeyValuePair<??>)listBox.SelectedItem;
    object value = pair.Value;
}
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically at runtime using reflection?  I know it's possible to use reflection with generic types and determine the key/value parameters, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do the rest after those values are retrieved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be something like the following. I wrote this in the answer box so the syntax may not be exactly right, but I've made it Wiki editable so anybody can fix up.

```
if (listBox.ItemsSource.IsGenericType && 
    typeof(IDictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(listBox.ItemsSource.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
{
    var method = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>).GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod();
    var item = method.Invoke(listBox.SelectedItem, null);
}
```

Comment: it'd probably perform better using the boxed value than using reflection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can't just box a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> to extract the value from it.

Comment: Your solution worked.  I changed the if statement to go ahead and just test "is IDictionary" (the typeof part of yours didn't work for some reason).  I also changed "typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)" to "listBox.SelectedItem"

Comment: @Guvante Actually, you can omit the type parameters when using `typeof` with a generic type.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

Comment: @TimGoodman: That is odd, I tried that syntax and got a compile error, removing.

Answer (score 14):

Check to see if it implements IDictionary.

See the definition of System.Collections.IDictionary to see what that gives you.

```
if (listBox.ItemsSource is IDictionary)
{
    DictionaryEntry pair = (DictionaryEntry)listBox.SelectedItem;
    object value = pair.Value;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Alternative when I realized KeyValuePair's aren't castable to DictionaryEntry

```
if (listBox.DataSource is IDictionary)
{
     listBox.ValueMember = "Value";
     object value = listBox.SelectedValue;
     listBox.ValueMember = ""; //If you need it to generally be empty.
}
```

This solution uses reflection, but in this case you don't have to do the grunt work, ListBox does it for you. Also if you generally have dictionaries as data sources you may be able to avoid reseting ValueMember all of the time.

Comment: Um, you know IDictionary<TKey,TValue> doesn't actually implement the IDictionary interface? So this won't work for generic dictionaries. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx

Comment: Also, even if it was a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> which does implement IDictionary, then it implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> so I'd expect the case to DictionaryEntry to fail.

Comment: Casting to DictionaryEntry does fail.  Still haven't figured out the solution yet.

Comment: Well to correct Greg Beech, I just pulled up Dictionary<>, and it does in fact implement IDictionary, even if IDictionary<> does not.
Forgot that although using an indexing method to get a DictionaryEntry would work, I can't cast the SelectedItem to it. Will fix if I find non-reflection solution.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was asked many years ago, but it is still visible publicly.

There were few examples proposed here in this topic and in this one: 
[Determine if type is dictionary [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956903/determine-if-type-is-dictionary)

but there are few mismatches, so I want to share my solution

**Short answer:**

```
var dictionaryInterfaces = new[]
{
    typeof(IDictionary<,>),
    typeof(IDictionary),
    typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>),
};

var dictionaries = collectionOfAnyTypeObjects
    .Where(d => d.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        .Any(t=> dictionaryInterfaces
            .Any(i=> i == t || t.IsGenericType && i == t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())))
```

**Longer answer:** 
I believe this is the reason why people make mistakes:

```
//notice the difference between IDictionary (interface) and Dictionary (class)
typeof(IDictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<,>)) // true 
typeof(IDictionary<int, int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<int, int>)); // true

typeof(IDictionary<int, int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<int, int>)); // true
typeof(IDictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<,>)); // false!! in contrast with above line this is little bit unintuitive
```

so let say we have these types:

```
public class CustomReadOnlyDictionary : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyClass>
public class CustomGenericDictionary : IDictionary<string, MyClass>
public class CustomDictionary : IDictionary
```

and these instances:

```
var dictionaries = new object[]
{
    new Dictionary<string, MyClass>(),
    new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyClass>(new Dictionary<string, MyClass>()),
    new CustomReadOnlyDictionary(),
    new CustomDictionary(),
    new CustomGenericDictionary()
};
```

so if we will use .IsAssignableFrom() method:

```
var dictionaries2 = dictionaries.Where(d =>
    {
        var type = d.GetType();
        return type.IsGenericType && typeof(IDictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }); // count == 0!!
```

we will not get any instance

so best way is to get all interfaces and check if any of them is dictionary interface:

```
var dictionaryInterfaces = new[]
{
    typeof(IDictionary<,>),
    typeof(IDictionary),
    typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>),
};

var dictionaries2 = dictionaries
    .Where(d => d.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        .Any(t=> dictionaryInterfaces
            .Any(i=> i == t || t.IsGenericType && i == t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))) // count == 5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check to see if it implements [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx). You'll just have to enumerate over using the [DictionaryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming from [Determine if type is dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956903/determine-if-type-is-dictionary), where none of the answers there adequately solve my issue.

The closest answer here comes from [Lukas Klusis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357702/lukas-klusis), but falls short of giving a `IsDictionary(Type type)` method. Here's that method, taking inspiration from his answer:

```c#
private static Type[] dictionaryInterfaces = 
{
  typeof(IDictionary<,>),
  typeof(System.Collections.IDictionary),
  typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>),
};

public static bool IsDictionary(Type type) 
{
   return dictionaryInterfaces
    .Any(dictInterface =>
        dictInterface == type || // 1
        (type.IsGenericType && dictInterface == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) || // 2
        type.GetInterfaces().Any(typeInterface => // 3
                                 typeInterface == dictInterface ||
                                 (typeInterface.IsGenericType && dictInterface == typeInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition())));
}
```

`// 1` addresses `public System.Collections.IDictionary MyProperty {get; set;}`

`// 2` addresses `public IDictionary<SomeObj, SomeObj> MyProperty {get; set;}`

`// 3` (ie the second `.Any`) addresses any scenario in which the `type` implements any one of the `dictionaryInterfaces` Types.

The issues with the other answers - assuming they address #3 - is that they don't address #1 and #2. Which is understandable, since getting and checking a Property's Type probably isn't a common scenario. But in case you're like me, and that scenario *is* part of your use-case, there you go!

Answer (score 0):

You could be a little more generic and ask instead if it implements `IDictionary`. Then the KeyValue collection will contina plain `Objects`.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology, referring to the non-generic versions as generic is probably confusing to some people (I know I always have to correct myself :P)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a warning is at place.

When you're testing if an object 'is a' something this or that, you're reimplementing (part of) the type system.  The first 'is a' is often swiftly followed by a second one, and soon your code is full of type checks, which ought to be very well handled by the type system - at least in an object oriented design.

Of course, I know nothing of the context of the question.  I do know a 2000 line file in our own codebase that handles 50 different object to String conversions... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(listBox.ItemsSource.GetType()))
{

}
```