# Cast object to a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a function in C# that operates on generic Dictionary's:

```
public static string DoStuff<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    // ... stuff happens here
}
```

I also have a function that loops over objects. If one of those objects is a Dictionary<>, I need to pass it to that generic function. However, I won't know what the types for the Key or Values are at compile-time:

```
foreach (object o in Values)
{
    if (/*o is Dictionary<??,??>*/)
    {
        var dictionary = /* cast o to some sort of Dictionary<> */;
        DoStuff(dictionary);
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: can you use IDictionary instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123181/testing-if-an-object-is-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp

Comment: Wouldn't I have to re-write the DoStuff function to use the IDictionary type? That's not really an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you can't make your method generic in the type of the `Values` collection, you can use dynamic:

```
foreach (object o in values)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();
    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
    {
        string str = DoStuff((dynamic)o);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use reflection:

```
foreach (object o in values)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();
    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
    {
        var typeParams = t.GetGenericArguments();
        var method = typeof(ContainingType).GetMethod("DoStuff").MakeGenericMethod(typeParams);
        string str = (string)method.Invoke(null, new[] { o });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Actually reflection code does not look as bad as I thought.

Answer (score 4):

Make your function generic too if you know that all dictionaries in `Value` collection are the same:

```
void DealWithIt<T,V>(IEnumerable Values)
{
foreach (object item in Values)
{
    var dictionary = item as Dictionary<T,V>;
    if (dictionary != null)
    {
        DoStuff<T,V>(dictionary);
    }
}
```

Otherwise consider using non-generic `IDictionary` to be passed to `DoStuff` before diving into serious reflection code.