# Determine if type is dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

How can I determine if Type is of `Dictionary<,>`

Currently the only thing that worked for me is if I actually know the arguments.

For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var isDict = dict.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>; // This Works
var isDict = dict.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<,>; // This does not work
```

But the dictionary won't always be `<string, object>` so how can I check whether it's a dictionary without knowing the arguments and without having to check the name (since we also have other classes that contain the word `Dictionary`.

Comment: `Dictionary<,>` objects implement `IDictionary` so possibly `typeof(IDictionary)`.

Comment: could there be primitives? I am not that familiar with C#, but isn't every class a descendant System.Object?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
Type t = dict.GetType();
bool isDict = t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>);
```

You can then get the key and value types:

```
Type keyType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type valueType = t.GetGenericArguments()[1];
```

Comment: GetGenericTypeDefinitions throw an exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException". Must be because i'm testing it against a non generic type. Stupid me!

Comment: @TheunArbeider - That should only happen if the type is not generic, are you including the `IsGenericType` condition?

Comment: Yup, forgot the isgenerictype :)

Comment: Why is this answer not over at the duplicate? I think it should be.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, but is missing the final piece I needed - converting the unknown object into a `Dictionary<,>`. This can be done by using `dynamic genericType = Convert.ChangeType(obj, t);`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `IsAssignableFrom` to check if type implements `IDictionary`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

var isDict = typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(dict.GetType());

Console.WriteLine(isDict); //prints true
```

This code will print false for all types, that don't implement `IDictionary` interface.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very simple way to do this and you were very nearly there.

Try this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var isDict = (dict.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
```

Comment: Nope, you need to check if the type is a generic one first. Otherwise, you may get `InvalidOperationException: 'This operation is only valid on generic types.'`

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<int, string> d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List<string> d3 = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine(d is System.Collections.IDictionary);
Console.WriteLine(d2 is System.Collections.IDictionary);
Console.WriteLine(d3 is System.Collections.IDictionary);
```

as all generic Dictionary types inherit from IDictionary interface, you may just check that

Comment: This looks nicely but does not work: "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments"

Comment: @BorisZinchenko just copy pasted this into a test and ran it, with no errors. And the error message you stated, looks like you are missing a Type in the dictionary definition. As in `Dictionary<string>` vs `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: you can see your code and the error here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJpHIi

Comment: The error requiring the generic parameters is there because the compiler thinks you want to use the `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` with no types. in my example i use the non-generic interface `System.Collections.IDictionary;`. Also if you look at the definition of the generic Dictionary class, it does implement the non generic IDictionary interface as per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. The code compiled correctly with explicit namespace resolution. I ve edited your answer in order that others were not confused as I were.