# Model binding to Dictionary<string,string> in Nancy

Tags: c#, model-binding, nancy

I can't bind JSON to `Dictionary<string,string>` in Nancy.

This route:

```
Get["testGet"] = _ =>
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
         {"hello", "world"},
         {"foo", "bar"}
    };

    return Response.AsJson(dictionary);
};
```

returns the following JSON, as expected:

```
{
    "hello": "world",
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

When I try and post this exact JSON back to this route:

```
Post["testPost"] = _ =>
{
    var data = this.Bind<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    return null;
};
```

I get the exception:

> The value "[Hello, world]" is not of type "System.String" and cannot
>   be used in this generic collection.

Is it possible to bind to `Dictionary<string,string>` using Nancys default model binding and, if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nancy doesn't have a [built-in converter](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/188bc90450b10d263495d0a33c4cec98a1903937/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/DefaultConverters) for dictionaries. Because of this you'd need to use `BindTo<T>()` like so

```
var data = this.BindTo(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

which will use the `CollectionConverter`. The issue with doing it like this is it will only add string values, so if you send

```
{
    "hello": "world",
    "foo": 123
}
```

your result will only contain the key `hello`.

If you want to capture all the values as strings, even if they aren't supplied as such, then you'll need to use a custom `IModelBinder`.

This will convert all the values to strings and return a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
public class StringDictionaryBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object Bind(NancyContext context, Type modelType, object instance, BindingConfig configuration, params string[] blackList)
    {
        var result = (instance as Dictionary<string, string>) ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();

        IDictionary<string, object> formData = (DynamicDictionary) context.Request.Form;

        foreach (var item in formData)
        {
            var itemValue = Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, typeof (string)) as string;

            result.Add(item.Key, itemValue);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public bool CanBind(Type modelType)
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/16956978/39605
        if (modelType.IsGenericType && modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Dictionary<,>))
        {
            if (modelType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof (string) &&
                modelType.GetGenericArguments()[1] == typeof (string))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Nancy will auto register this for you and you can bind your models as you normally would.

```
var data1 = this.Bind<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var data2 = this.BindTo(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```