# Detect if it's a Dictionary and the key is assignable from a specific type

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

I'm working on a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm), and override the `CanConvert`-method.

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) ||
            TypeImplementsGenericInterface(objectType, typeof(IDictionary<,>)));
}

private static bool TypeImplementsGenericInterface(Type concreteType, Type interfaceType)
{
    return concreteType.GetInterfaces()
           .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);
}
```

Very much inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043792/4949005). The thing is that I only want to return `true` if the key of the dictionary is of a specific type. For example, I only want to return true if the key is of type `Bar`, or inherits/implements `Bar`. The value doesn't matter. The value can be of any type.

```
Dictionary<string, int> // false
Dictionary<Bar, string> // true
Dictionary<Foo, string> // false
Dictionary<Bar, Foo> // true
Dictionary<BarSubClass, Foo> // true
```

How can I, from a `Type`, detect if it's a `Dictionary` and the key is assignable from a specific type?

What I've tried so far:

```
typeof(IDictionary<Bar, object>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
```

Unfortunately this returns `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing if an Object is a Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123181/testing-if-an-object-is-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @derape - The difference is that I don't have an instance. I have a type. Also, I already know how to check if it's assignable from Dictionary. I need to check if it has a specific key as well.

Comment: You'll have to dig into the interface definitions [Generic Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @smoksnes you don't need an instance to do that, just the type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the generic type and the first type argument (`TKey`):

```
concreteType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType &&
    (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)) &&
    typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
```

Comment: Works great. Exactly what I was looking for.