# IDictionary`2 not assignable from Dictionary`2

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I want to determine wether a given `Type` object refers to a generic dictionary. To achieve this I tried the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123227/3959259). But to my surprise, the following test code prints `not a generic dictionary!`

```
private void Test()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var type = dict.GetType();
    
    if (type.IsGenericType &&
            typeof(IDictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
        Console.WriteLine("a generic dictionary");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("not a generic dictionary!");
}
```

How can it be that `` IDictionary`2 `` is not assignable from `` Dictionary`2 `` or do I something fundamentally wrong?

In case it matters, I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2015 with .NET 4.6 as target.

Comment: is it even meaningful to ask about assignability of open generic types? they can't even exist... note that `typeof(IDictionary<string,string>).IsAssignableFrom(type)` will return `true`

Comment: @MarcGravell In my real code type is determined via reflection, so it could be anything. At this point I want to only know wether it is a generic dictionary for selecting an appropriate GUI component. The concrete types of `Key` and `Value` will be determined and handeled later in that component.

Comment: yeah, you can't do that; you *could* check what interfaces `type` implements, and for each: see whether the interface type is a generic type, and if so: check whether the generic type definition is `typeof(IDictionary<,>)`, but: you can't use `IsAssignableFrom`, because assignability *simply isn't defined* in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search the type's interfaces and check if any are an instantiation of the `IDictionary<K, V>` interface:

```
bool isDict = type.GetInterfaces().Any(it => it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>));
```